# How to reduce code in a JPA CriteriaBuilder

Tags: jpa, reduce

I'm new to JPA with the CriteriaBuilder and want to reduce some lines of code.

***cb.and*** is usefull to add predicate's, but what if they are ***null***?

**How can I reduce these lines of code?** Thanks!
I'm worried about the readability of the code...

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery(OrganizationEntity.class);

Root<OrganizationEntity> root = cq.from(OrganizationEntity.class);

Predicate predicateFrom = null;
Predicate predicateTo = null;
if (from != null) {
     predicateFrom = cb.ge(root.get(OrganizationEntity_.id), from);
}
if (to != null) {
     predicateTo = cb.le(root.get(OrganizationEntity_.id), to);
}

if(predicateFrom != null && predicateTo != null) {
    cq.where(cb.and(predicateFrom,predicateTo));
} else if (predicateFrom != null && predicateTo == null) {
    cq.where(predicateFrom);
} else if (predicateFrom == null && predicateTo != null) {
    cq.where(predicateTo);
} 

TypedQuery<OrganizationEntity> query = em.createQuery(cq);

list = query.getResultList();
return list;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you could do is create your predicate list

```
List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

if (from != null) {
     predicates .add(cb.ge(root.get(OrganizationEntity_.id), from));
}
if (to != null) {
   predicates .add(cb.le(root.get(OrganizationEntity_.id), to));
}

if (predicates.size()>0{
    cq.where(cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates
                .size()])));
}
```